# How may I resolve this error? - Delegate 'System.Action<object>' does not take 0 arguments

Tags: c#, task

The following code:

```
var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { listBox1.Items.Add("Starting to crawl " + srMainSiteURL + "..."); } , ui);
```

is resulting in the following error:

> `Delegate 'System.Action<object>' does not take 0 arguments`

After looking at other threads, I have not been able to determine nor understand the cause of the error. Please advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you did use

```
public Task StartNew(Action<object> action, object state)
```

I do think you wanted to use

```
public Task StartNew(Action action, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions, TaskScheduler scheduler)
```

So your example would become:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { listBox1.Items.Add("Starting to crawl " + srMainSiteURL + "..."); }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, ui);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to call [`StartNew(Action<object>, object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321456.aspx). However, your lambda expression cannot be converted into an `Action<object>`.

Options:

- Remove your second argument (`ui`) so that you end up calling [`StartNew(Action)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx) which is fine for the lambda expression you've provided. For example:

  ```
  // The braces were redundant, by the way...
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => listBox1.Items.Add("..."));
  ```
- Change your lambda expression to accept a parameter:

  ```
  Task.Factory.StartNew(state => listBox1.Items.Add("..."), ui);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You are using this one: [TaskFactory.StartNew Method (Action, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321456.aspx)

that takes an `Action<object>`, so you should write `p => { ... }`, the `ui` is the second parameter of `StartNew` (an object).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify a `TaskScheduler` in your call to `Task.Factory.StartNew()` you need to use one of the overloads that accepts it as an argument. You are calling the overload

```
StartNew(Action<object> action, object state)
```

which is probably not what you intended?

To use `Task.Factory.StartNew()` with a scheduler you also need to specify a `CancellationToken` and some `TaskCreationOptions`, that is the [method documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781658.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong overload. If you want to pass a `TaskScheduler`, use this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => { ... }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, ui );
```