# Set TextBlock from Async Completion Handler

Tags: c#, asynchronous, microsoft-metro

I would like to set the text on the `MainPage` of my app, based on the response of an Async call to Web Service.

Im getting a "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread". So I know that I need to execute the

```
MainPage.TB_Response.text = response;
```

On the Primary/Main Thread, but I am unsure as to how i would go about this

Edit: Here is my Response Handler

```
    private void ReadResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ReadResponse");
        try
        {
            // The downloaded resource ends up in the variable named content. 
            var content = new MemoryStream();

            // State of request is asynchronous.
            //RequestState myRequestState = (RequestState)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest2.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);

            //do whatever
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                responseStream.CopyTo(content);
                byte[] data = content.ToArray();
                if (data.Length > 0)
                {
                    string temp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
                    MainPage.TB_Reponse.Text = temp;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(temp);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Edit2: My MainPage Class

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public static TextBlock TB_Reponse;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MainPage.TB_Reponse = this.TB_Response;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void BTN_Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your asynchronous call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this solution to solve my problem

[Delegate 'System.Action<object>' does not take 0 arguments - C# - Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780812/delegate-system-actionobject-does-not-take-0-arguments-c-sharp-task)

I Setup my ServerRequest object to store the current synchronisation context

```
ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
```

then in my Response Handler I run the following:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                            {
                                MainPage.TB_Reponse.Text = temp; //This is run on the same thread as the UI
                            },System.Threading.CancellationToken.None , TaskCreationOptions.None, instance.ui);
```

Comment: You can also wrap call on one thread with the CoreDispatcher.RunAsyc method that will put the delegate code onto the UI thread.

Comment: Are you referring to wrapping the response handler or the UI Interaction code with CoreDispatcher?

Comment: Whatever code you want to have run on the UI thread - i.e., anything that touches UI controls